# Exporting gtest functions cause failed tests to pass

Tags: c++, c++11, googletest

I am attempting to write commonly used functionality for testing into a separate dll.  When I do this, I will get test failed reports as expected, but the final report will say the test passed.

```
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from MyFoo
[ RUN      ] MyFoo.fooTest
C:\Foo\Foo.cpp(2): error: Value of: false
  Actual: false
Expected: true
[       OK ] MyFoo.fooTest (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from MyFoo(0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test case ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.
```

As you can see, the test failed, but the report says it passed.

This is a simple example of my exported function:

```
// Foo.dll

// Foo.h
FOO_EXPORT void Foo();

// Foo.cpp
#include <Foo.h>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

void Foo()
{
    ::testing::UnitTest::GetInstance(); // 0x000007fecef5a590
    EXPECT_TRUE(false);
}
```

This is a simple example of my gtest executable:

```
// TestMyFoo.exe
#include <Foo.h>    
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

TEST(MyFoo, fooTest)
{
    ::testing::UnitTest::GetInstance(); // 0x000000003f9419d8
    Foo();
}
```

Is there something I'm doing incorrectly when it comes to exporting a google test?  Am I allowed to even do this(please say yes)?

Edit: I believe part of the issue has to do with the UnitTest singleton.
I edited my code example to better illustrate the issue.  The pointer to the UnitTest object should be the same but it is not.  Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: See [this question](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/FAQ#I_put_my_tests_in_a_library_and_Google_Test_doesn%27t_run_the) in Google Test FAQ.

Comment: @AndréSassi Thank you. The Visual C++ bug was not the issue but I was not building my gtest libraries as DLLs, which was the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As posted in the comments by AndreSassi. The [GTest Primer FAQ](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/FAQ#I_put_my_tests_in_a_library_and_Google_Test_doesn%27t_run_the) explains that the gtest libraries must be compiled as DLLs if you want to link your own DLLs to the main test executable.

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and the bug the FAQ mentions does not appear to be an issue.  Just that I wasn't building gtest as a DLL.